# How to change error message in apex5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In apex5.0, I have a page Item Ref_no define as number and a dynamic action associated with it that fill other Page Items.

when entered an incorrect ID getting below error message:
Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for Execute PL/SQL Code.

Is there a way to customise this error to 'Enter Correct Reference'

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the pl/sql, or log, but it seems as though you need to add some error handling within that code.

E.g.

```
Declare
   l_temp number;
Begin
   SELECT 1
       INTO l_temp
      FROM dual
    WHERE 1 = 0;
     EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Enter Correct Reference');
End;
```

[Oracle doc on error handling](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/errors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

On the process you have Error section when you can put text if operation fail. In case you try to put data in report you have section **No Data Found** in region atributes.

Comment: Do we have this Error sector for a page Item?  Got this statement dynamic action SELECT NAME1
INTO :P3_NAME
FROM TBL_ENTITLE 
WHERE REF_NO = :P3_ID;

Comment: For item use the answer of @hisnameismyname2 . **raise_application_error(-20101, 'Name not found');**

Comment: thanks, have used both solutions.. btw wht ur email add got some queries for a design pls..

Comment: I think it's not a good practice to post information that is not related to the question.  You can find some contact information in my profile. :)